# In Jellybean, camera intent returns RESULT.CANCELLED when using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider

I followed the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) to execute camera intent in my app.
It works in 5.0+ devices but not in Jellybean.

In 4.1(JB) to 4.4 (KK), native camera app shows "Unfortunately, camera has stopped error" after capturing image. In my app's onActivityResult, the result returned is RESULT.CANCELLED always. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The camera intent works correctly in JB if I don't use fileprovider and fetch uri using Uri.fromFile(file).

Following is my code

```
// MainActivity.java
File f = PhotoHelper.createImageFile(this);
photoPath = "file:" + f.getAbsolutePath();
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", f);
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.NEW_TOPIC_VIA_PHOTO);

// PhotoHelper.java
public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
   String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
   String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
   File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
   return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir);
}

// AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>

// file_paths.xml
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="App_Images"
        path="Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in code by granting per url-permission.

https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#.4ip8b7yqe

for official doc: look at section 4
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

More example:
https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/granting-content-provider-uri-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

I do this for Android 4.3 Jelly Bean and for Android 8 Oreo:

```
void startCamera() {
        try {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
            else
            {
                boolean focus = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature( "android.hardware.camera.autofocus");
                //displayMsg(context, "In startCamera AutoFocus = " + focus);
                dispatchTakePictureIntent4();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            displayMsg(context, "In startCamera " + e.toString());

        }
    }

 public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {

        try {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    displayMsg(context, "Error occurred while creating the File " + ex.toString());
                    return;
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    //rww OLD here
                    //Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());

                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(TellYourStoryActivity.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            createImageFile());

                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);//added RWW
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);


                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            displayMsg(context, "dispatchTakePictureIntent " + e.toString());

        }

    }

    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent4() throws IOException {
        try {
            // MainActivity.java
            File f = this.createImageFile4(this);
            if (f == null)
            {
                displayMsg(context, "dispatchTakePictureIntent 444" + " file f is null");
                return;
            }
            String photoPath = "file:" + f.getAbsolutePath();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + f.getAbsolutePath();
            mCurrentAbsolutePhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            //displayMsg(context, "dispatchTakePictureIntent 444 photopath\n" + photoPath);

            //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", f);

            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(f);
            //displayMsg(context, "dispatchTakePictureIntent 444 uri" + photoURI.toString());
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, NEW_TOPIC_VIA_PHOTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            displayMsg(context, "dispatchTakePictureIntent 444" + e.toString());

        }
    }

    // PhotoHelper.java
    public  File createImageFile4(Context context) throws IOException {
        try {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            displayMsg(context, "createImageFile4 444" + e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }

 public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        File image = null;
        //displayMsg(context, "In createImageFile  ");
        try {


            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
            image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            RWWmCurrentPhotoPath = "content:/" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            mCurrentAbsolutePhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            displayMsg(context, "In createImageFile  " + e.toString());
        }
        return image;
    }
```